# Pass array to function and loop over values by index

Tags: python, loops

I keep getting a TypeError: unsupported operand type for +: 'int' and 'list'
so I guess the array isn't being indexed? Please assist.

```
def main():
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    length = len(arr)
    maxAns = msa2(length, arr)
    print maxAns

def msa2(length, *arr):
    maxThus = 0
    for i in range(0, length):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(i, length):
            sum = sum + arr[j]     # how to get value in index j
            max(maxThus, sum)
    return maxThus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `*arr`; remove the `*` wildcard character and your code will work.

With the wildcard character, the argument passed into `msa2` is seen as one of potentially more extra positional arguments, so `arr` inside `msa2` is a list of those arguments, with the first element being the list you passed in when you called `msa2`:

```
>>> def foo(*args):
...     print args
... 
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
([1, 2, 3],)
```

Your function also will always return `0`; you do not update `maxThus` anywhere. You probably meant to assign the result of `max(maxThus, sum)` to `maxThus`:

```
maxThus = max(maxThus, sum)
```

Comment: Awesome, so the wildcard is like a list of lists. Thx for the bug fix too. Voted as useful.